# My code is not entering in the while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

This a part of my code and this the only part that keeps getting wrong. It won't enter the while loop even if it is false. I'm still just learning Java so I think maybe I did something wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CateringBooking {
String serv;
int menuSet;
String timeAndDate;
boolean valid = true;

//Selecting the kind of service method
public String kindOfService () {
    System.out.println("1. TYPE OF SERVICE SELECTION");
    System.out.println("Select the kind of service you want.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("A: Basic");
    System.out.println("B: Premium");
    System.out.println("C: Deluxe");
    System.out.println("D: Fiesta Deluxe");

    Scanner myService = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Letter of your choice: ");
    String selectService = myService.nextLine();

    
    while (valid != true) {
        if (selectService.equals("A") || selectService.equals("a")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Basic service");
        } else if (selectService.equals("B") || selectService.equals("b")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Premium service");
        } else if (selectService.equals("C") || selectService.equals("c")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Deluxe service");
        } else if (selectService.equals("D") || selectService.equals("d")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Fiesta Deluxe service");
        } else {
            valid = false;
            System.out.println("Your choice is not available. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    serv = selectService;
    return selectService;
}
```

Comment: Maybe reset `valid = false;` before the loop.

Comment: I don't see any main method. There should be ```public static void main(String[] args) {
        CateringBooking cateringBooking = new CateringBooking();
        cateringBooking.kindOfService();
    }``` and you no need to use ```!=``` to check in ```while``` loop. Just use attribute. Change ```valid = false;``` and ```while (valid)``` it should work.

Answer (score 2):

On the 6th line you have declared `boolean valid = true;` and haven't ever set it to `false` later in the code, so it does not enter the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, I am understanding you want to choose option's if the option is not select again try the option in the while loop. You can try like below way.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CateringBooking {
String serv;
int menuSet;
String timeAndDate;
boolean valid = true;


public String kindOfService() {
    System.out.println("1. TYPE OF SERVICE SELECTION");
        
    Scanner myService = new Scanner(System.in);
    String selectService = "";
    valid = false;
    while (valid != true) {
        System.out.println("Select the kind of service you want.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("A: Basic");
        System.out.println("B: Premium");
        System.out.println("C: Deluxe");
        System.out.println("D: Fiesta Deluxe");
        System.out.print("Letter of your choice: ");
        selectService = myService.nextLine();
        
        if (selectService.equals("A") || selectService.equals("a")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Basic service");
        } else if (selectService.equals("B") || selectService.equals("b")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Premium service");
        } else if (selectService.equals("C") || selectService.equals("c")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Deluxe service");
        } else if (selectService.equals("D") || selectService.equals("d")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("You've selected: Fiesta Deluxe service");
        } else {
            valid = false;
            System.out.println("Your choice is not available. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    serv = selectService;
    return selectService;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You set the boolean to true on the beggining(line 6), the while condition is :

```
while(valid != true)
```

The same as:

```
while(valid==false)
```

So never enters the loop , just change the declaration to false(6th line):

```
boolean valid = true;
```